# How to overcome the issue of code block similarity with "visibilityOfElementLocated"?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

```
public class TestingLogin {

    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    public void setup()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://test.admin.placer.life/login");
    }

    @Test(priority=9)
    public void reset_null_email()
    {
        LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/a")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/p[contains(text(),'Reset Password')]")));
        login.set_reset_email("");
        login.click_reset_button(); 
        WebDriverWait wait_reset_psw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait_reset_psw.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/span[2]")));
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/span[2]")).getText(),"The email field is required.");
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }

    @Test(priority=10)
    public void reset_invalid_email()
    {
        LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/a")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/p[contains(text(),'Reset Password')]")));
        login.set_reset_email("a@gmail.com");
        login.click_reset_button(); 
        WebDriverWait wait_reset_psw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait_reset_psw.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/span[2]")));
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/span[2]")).getText(),"The email field is required.");
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }       
    @AfterTest
    public void close()
    {
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Hey all,
I have tried the reset_invalid_email() with "**visibilityOfElementLocated**",but it is cause to fail the testcase because similarity of code blocks,i guess.So I have tried it with "**elementToBeClickable**".But it is also caused to make same error.

Please help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In Which step you are getting an error?

Comment: You are getting error after login page

Comment: provide Html and error stacktrace.

Comment: PASSED: reset_null_email                                                                                  
FAILED: reset_invalid_email

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/p[contains(text(),'Reset Password')] (tried for 120 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: @Subburaj This is the error I got when I run this on Eclipse

Comment: @bhupathituraga Yea login page loaded for the @Test(priority = 10),but not able to click the "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/a")).click();"

Answer (score 0):

As per your question as you mentioned of `reset_invalid_email()` method, you can use the solution below:

A few words:

- Whenever you intend to click an element use `elementToBeClickable()` method.
- Firefox Browser opens in *Maximized Mode* so you don't need to use `driver.manage().window().maximize();`
- If you need to maximize any browser use the **Options* Class instead.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.
- Your working code block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
  import org.testng.Assert;
  import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
  import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  public class q50598754 {

      WebDriver driver;
      @BeforeTest
      public void setup()
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
          driver=new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://test.admin.placer.life/login");
      }

      @Test(priority=10)
      public void reset_invalid_email()
      {
          //LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("I forgot my password"))).click();
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/p[contains(text(),'Reset Password')]")));
          //login.set_reset_email("a@gmail.com");
          //skipped to reproduce the error message The email field is required
          //login.click_reset_button(); 
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block.btn-flat")).click();;
          Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.form-group.has-feedback.has-error span.help-block")).getText(),"The email field is required.");
      } 

      @AfterTest
      public void close()
      {
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  PASSED: reset_invalid_email

  ===============================================
      Default test
      Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================


  ===============================================
  Default suite
  Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
  ===============================================
  ```

Comment: This works fine when only using this method in the code.Did u try both methods together?This is not working with another method,thats the problem

Comment: @user3806999 This answer was constructed as per your question about `I have tried the reset_invalid_email() ... but it is cause to fail` so it won't be working for _with another method_ as the workflows are different. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.